# Remove multiple lines from file with PHP

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have a file called 'file.php' in which is the following code:

```
<?php
$var = 'something';
echo '<p>' . $var . '</p>';
?>
```

Is it possible to delete these lines with PHP, without altering the rest of the file?

Comment: Succinct & to the point.

Comment: `file_get_contents`, `str_replace`, `file_put_contents`

Comment: Depends what you want to do... If you want to make a permanent change, and change the file on the server, you can do what vonUbisch suggests. If the problem is what is "echo-ed", you can also delete the output from the HTML on client-side using JS... what is the context ?

Comment: I just want to delete all those lines, before it gets echo-ed

Comment: Why don't you just edit the file then ?

Comment: Haha, yeah it's seems pretty dumb. But I want to do multiple of these deletions using one php file. So when you open the file, multiple of those strings in multiple files will be removed(as well as the file itself, using unlink).

Comment: Then you should use @vonUbisch 's solution on a loop on every files you wish...

Answer (score 0):

Once these lines have been output (sent to the browser) you will not be able to "delete" them solely using PHP.

You'll need to use a client-side scripting language such as JavaScript to get a handle on the `<p>` tag for example and then either hide it or remove it from the DOM.